# Blank screen when using CI_Session

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, cookies

While developing (actually right before moving to production, how ironic), my CI_Session from CodeIgniter stopped working.

When I clean sessions&cookies from the browser, the website works. However, **after refreshing**, or clicking any link (in fact, doing whatever), the session stops working and shows a Blank screen. It is weird, because I didn't touch anything, and after rolling back to a previous version, it still didn't work. The config wasn't changed, the load procedures are there as always and the config hasn't been changed since we started coding.

When changing any parameter related to cookie names or whatever, it works again once, and after that it shows a Blank screen again.

My original config was:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = TRUE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;

$config['cookie_prefix']    = "";
$config['cookie_domain']    = "";
$config['cookie_path']      = "/";
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems weird, but it just passed out because one silly thing: I defined a `string_helper.php`, while it already was on the system. As custom helpers have preference, it probably picked mine when `CI_Session` asked for it, looking for `random_string`.

So, to sum up, renaming it to `my_string_helper` fixed the issue. Quite silly, indeed.